# Merge and align center cell using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to export data to excel using **Apache poi**.
 Now the problem that I am facing is that I am unable to merge rows and align them in the center.

Code for export data is:

```
List<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>> lstReportHeader = null;
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

//Set Header Font
HSSFFont headerFont = wb.createFont();
headerFont.setBoldweight(headerFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);

//Set Header Style
CellStyle headerStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
headerStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
headerStyle.setAlignment(headerStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
headerStyle.setFont(headerFont);
headerStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
int rowCount= 0;
Row header;
header = sheet.createRow(0);//its for header 
Cell cell ;//= header.createCell(0);
for(int j = 0;j < 4; j++) {
    cell = header.createCell(j);
    if(j == 0) {
        cell.setCellValue("ItemWise List");
    }
    cell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
}
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowCount, rowCount, 0, lstReportFormHeader.size()-1));
header = sheet.createRow(0);
        cell = header.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("Sr. No");
        cell = header.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue("Item Name");
        cell = header.createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue("Qty");
        cell = header.createCell(3);
cell.setCellValue("Rate");
```

Now I want to **ItemWise List** merge and make it align center.

Answer (score 19):

My solution was to merge the cells by their positions, then created a cell (reference to the first block of the merged cells) to assign a value and then set the alignment throught the [CellUtil](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html)

```
// Merges the cells
CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(start, start, j, j + 1);
sheet.addMergedRegion(cellRangeAddress);

// Creates the cell
Cell cell = CellUtil.createCell(row, j, entry.getKey());

// Sets the allignment to the created cell
CellUtil.setAlignment(cell, workbook, CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Comment: Use `CellUtil.setAlignment(cell, HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);`, the method ***setAlignment(Cell cell, Workbook workbook, short align)*** is deprecated now from 3.15-beta2.

Answer (score 16):

Merge like:::

```
 Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

Row row = sheet.createRow((short) 1);
Cell cell = row.createCell((short) 1);
cell.setCellValue("This is a test of merging");

sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
        1, //first row (0-based)
        1, //last row  (0-based)
        1, //first column (0-based)
        2  //last column  (0-based)
));

// Write the output to a file
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

For aligning also check the below official link of Apache poi:::

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Alignment

Comment: Yes you are right i am able to merge cell but i could not able to make it allign center

Answer (score 12):

After study I found that after merging 7 cells, merged cell id will be 0 so I applied following style to cell id 0 using following style.

```
headerStyle.setAlignment(headerStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me and I think it's cleaner:

```
/**
 * Merge and center the cells specified by range
 * @param startCell the first cell in the cells to be merged
 * @param range the range of the cells to be merged
 */
private static void mergeAndCenter(Cell startCell, CellRangeAddress range) {
    startCell.getSheet().addMergedRegion(range);
    CellStyle style = startCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    style.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
    startCell.setCellStyle(style);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think it's "cleaner"? Insight as to why or how something works does a lot to help other users.

Comment: I agree with the poster.  It definitely is cleaner since you are using the D.R.Y. method.  If there is a problem with this code you only have to fix it here.

Comment: In newer version use this 
style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);

Answer (score 4):

Well what worked for me is to set all the merged cells' Cellstyle to CENTER ALIGN. Whether you put the XSSFSheet.addMergedRegion() method before or after setting the cellstyle values to center don't matter.

```
    private void insertXlsHeader(XSSFSheet sheet){
    ....
    //first cell for row1       
    cell = row1.createCell(colstart);
    cell.setCellType(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    cell.setCellValue("COURSES");
    setHeaderCellStyle(sheet,cell);

    //first cell for row2
    cell = row2.createCell(colstart);
    setHeaderCellStyle(sheet,cell);

    //first cell for row3
    cell = row3.createCell(colstart);
    setHeaderCellStyle(sheet,cell);

    //merged the first cells of rows 1 to 3
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(ROW1, ROW3, colstart, colstart));
    ...
    }

private void setHeaderCellStyle(XSSFSheet sheet,org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell) {
    CellStyle s = null;

        s = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
        cell.setCellStyle(s);

    Font f = sheet.getWorkbook().createFont();

    f.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);


    s.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    s.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    s.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    s.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    s.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
    s.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    s.setFont(f);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding, you have start and end cells for merging and you want to merge the cell ranges and align the cell content. If I am right, you can use the following method:

```
/**
 * @param startCell: first cell of merging area
 * @param endCell: last cell of merging area
 */

public static void mergeAndAlignCenter(HSSFCell startCell, HSSFCell endCell){
    //finding reference of start and end cell; will result like $A$1
    CellReference startCellRef= new CellReference(startCell.getRowIndex(),startCell.getColumnIndex());
    CellReference endCellRef = new CellReference(endCell.getRowIndex(),endCell.getColumnIndex());
    // forming string of references; will result like $A$1:$B$5 
    String cellRefernce = startCellRef.formatAsString()+":"+endCellRef.formatAsString();
    //removing $ to make cellRefernce like A1:B5
    cellRefernce = cellRefernce.replace("$","");
    //passing cellRefernce to make a region 
    CellRangeAddress region = CellRangeAddress.valueOf(cellRefernce);
    //use region to merge; though other method like sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,1,4,1));
    // is also available, but facing some problem right now.
    startCell.getRow().getSheet().addMergedRegion( region );
    //setting alignment to center
    CellUtil.setAlignment(startCell, wb, CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As answered above, merging cells can be achieved using

```
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(frstRow, lastRow, firstColumnIndex, lastColumnIndex));
```

But for aligning cells vertically,recently I faced similar issue and I tried above answer, but using

```
CellUtil.setAlignment(dataCell, workbook, CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
```

aligned Date formatted cells to Horizontal Left aligned. So I used following method to set only Vertical Alignment of Cell content.

```
CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(dataCell, workbook,CellUtil.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT,CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
```

I hope this helps!!

***Happy Coding***

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
style.setVerticalAlignment()
```

to set the vertical alignments instead of

```
style.setAlignment().
```

Answer (score 0):

We can merge the column along with we can vertically and horizontally align too.

I had the rows 2 to 10 of column A having the same values.

[image]

I used the below code to merge the data where the variable `sheet` is `XSSFSheet`. The parameters of `CellRangeAddress` have the parameters are start row, last row, start column and last column. In my example, the value `USA` starts from 2nd row (index is 1) and the last value of `USA` is in 10th row and column is the 1st column.

```
CellRangeAddress ca = new CellRangeAddress(1,9,0,0);
sheet.addMergedRegion(ca);
```

When I executed the above code, the cell was merged but the text was not aligned to center.

[image]

To overcome this issue, I utilized the class `CellStyle` and `Cell`. Get the 2nd row of 1st column text to `cell` variable. Now set the vertical and horizontal alignment to the `cellStyle` and set this style to the `cell` which will align the text to the center.

```
Cell cell = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(0);
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Below is the final result

[image]

**Additional references** :

1. Jar files used

[image]

2. Import statements

   [image]